# Mechanisms of setText() in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea, settext

I try to show some text in my `JTextArea` in runtime. But when I use a loop of `setText` to show text in order, it only show the text of the last loop
Here is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
     jTextArea1.setText("Example "+i);
}
```

I want it to show `"Example 1", "Example 2",..,"Example 9"`. But it only show one time "`Example 9`"

Anyone can explain it for me??

Comment: I forget to change "QUang" become "Example". Sorry for everyone :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setText` does just that, it "sets the text" of field to the value your provide, removing all previous content.

What you want is [`JTextArea#append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String))

If you're using Java 8, another option might be [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    joiner.add("QUang " + i);
}
jTextArea1.setTexy(joiner.toString());
```

(assuming you want to replace the text each time the `actionPerformed` method is called, but you can still use `append`)

**Update based on assumptions around comments**

I "assume" you mean you want each `String` to be displayed for a short period of time and then replaced with the next `String`.

Swing is a single threaded environment, so anything that blocks the Event Dispatching Thread, like loops, will prevent the UI from been updated.  Instead, you need to use a Swing `Timer` to schedule a callback at regular intervals and make change the UI on each tick, for example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String[] messages = {
            "Example 1",
            "Example 2",
            "Example 3",
            "Example 4",
            "Example 5",
            "Example 6",
            "Example 7",
            "Example 8",
            "Example 9",
        };

        private JTextArea ta;
        private int index;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(1, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    index = 0;
                    timer.start();
                }
            });
            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (index < messages.length) {
                        ta.setText(messages[index]);
                    } else {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: hmm... but does OP want to show them all, or one-by-one?

Comment: @bayou.io *"I want it to show "Example 1", "Example 2",..,"Example 9". But it only show one time "Example 9""* and based on the use of `for-loop`, this seems to be what they are attempting to do

Comment: yeah, it seems so, but it's often difficult to parse the questioner's wording:)

Comment: Yeah, My English is not good. Hope you can understand what i mean :((.

Comment: I want  to see the text in my jTextArea is "Example 1". Then it become "Example 2" and so on. At last, it is "Example 9".
But in my program, it only show "Example 9". Changing text didnt happen

Comment: On each click on after a small delay?

Comment: yeah, maybe add some code to have a small delay. But problem is not that. Problem is jTextArea only show once when i run 9 command settext()
You can run to see this problem

Comment: I understand "why" it's happening, it's understanding "what" you actuallt want

Comment: That code need a specified delay. But if you dont know how much time delayed, like read from a BufferReader in a for-loop, can i still use Timer???
`BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

   String s = "";
   while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
   }`

Comment: A `SwingWorker` might be better, but some idea of what you're trying to achieve might also help

Comment: I have found some interesting things. When i use Frame to show the text by TextArea, its ok. Dont need any thing like Timer. I think problem is the different of jTextArea and TextArea but im not sure

Comment: You're talking about two different APIs, AWT and Swing (if I'm reading it right), so there a significant differences